# How to output a dictionary that finds maximum frequency values from a list?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a code that loops through a string of Text, with a k-mer, and outputs the most frequent patterns. (Please note I am also a beginner coder). I am using Juptyer notebook, and whenever I try to run my code, there is no output. (Maybe it's something to do with Juptyer)? For example, let's say my Text is GATGATATAC, and k-mer is 3, then I would like to output the most frequent patterns and show that as an indexed dictionary with the frequencies of each 3-letter pattern word.

```
    def FrequentWords(Text, k):
        words = []
        freq = FrequencyMap(Text, k)
        m = max(freq.values())
        for key in freq:
            if freq[key] == m:
                words.append(key)
    Text = 'GATTACCGACGTATGCTACTCCGATACGATAT'
    k = 3
    return words
```

I am not really sure where I should define Text and k, in order to test the code (which also could be an issue). As I said, I am using Juptyer notebook and when I press run nothing happens.

Comment: use return inside the functiion

Comment: @Lari : You had you `return` statement outside the function. And you did not call your function `FrequentWords`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant this:

```
def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    words = []
    freq = FrequencyMap(Text, k)
    m = max(freq.values())
    for key in freq:
        if freq[key] == m:
            words.append(key)
    return words

Text = 'GATTACCGACGTATGCTACTCCGATACGATAT'
k = 3
FrequentWords(Text, k)
```

Also, you can simplify your function a bit with a list comprehension:

```
def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    freq = FrequencyMap(Text, k)
    m = max(freq.values())
    return [key for key in freq if freq[key] == m]
```